# Hat der "Rosenmontag" etwas mit Rosen zu tun?

Tags: etymology, history

Im Karneval wird der Rosenmontag als Tag vor dem Faschingsdienstag in großen Teilen der Republik mit Umzügen gefeiert:

[Bild vom Rosenmontagsumzug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M0db.jpg)

Nach [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rosenmontag) und nach [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GR07477) soll sich *"Rosen-"* vom *"rasenden Montag"* herleiten. Allerdings schreibt die [Süddeutsche Zeitung](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/panorama/hintergrund-als-rosenmontag-noch-rosensonntag-war-1.826226):

> Um 1830 ging der Name dieses Rosensonntagskomitees auf den am Montag vor Aschermittwoch abgehaltenen Umzug über. Andere Städte wie Mainz und Düsseldorf übernahmen nach und nach diese Kölner Bezeichnung. Einer Minderheitsmeinung zufolge stimmt das alles aber gar nicht - Rosenmontag leitet sich demnach von dem niederrheinischen Wort "rosen" für rasen, toben ab.

Demnach soll es sich bei der Herkunfts von *"rasender Montag"* um eine "Minderheitsmeinung" handeln.

Was ist nun richtig? Gibt es eine verlässliche Referenz woher sich *"Rosenmontag"* ableitet?

Comment: Meyers Großes Handlexikon (19. Auflage) sagt auch nur: "rhein. Bezeichnung für den Fastnachtsmontag; nach 1830 in Köln belegt."

Comment: Im etymologischen Duden (Band 7 des Duden in 10 Bänden) in Auflage zwei von 1989 steht hingegen: "Die Bezeichnung für den Montag vor Fastnachtsdienstag hat sich aus _niederrhein._ rasen[d]montag (beachte _köln._ rose "toben, tollen, ausgelassen sein") entwickelt und bedeutet demnach also eigentlich "rasender (wilder, toller) Montag". Außerhalb des Rheinlandes wird das Bestimmungswort von 'Rosenmontag' gewöhnlich als Plural des Blumennamens 'Rose' aufgefaßt."

Comment: Meyers Enzyklopädisches Lexikon (1977) entspricht sinngemäß Meyers Großem Handlexikon. Seltsam ist, dass auch der etymologische Duden von Meyers Lexikonverlag herausgegeben wurde, aber eine von den anderen Lexika aus dem gleichen Verlag abweichende Erklärung aufweist. Den drei Lexika kann jetzt in Bezug auf Verlässlichkeit zu diesem Thema nicht mehr trauen. Vielleicht gibt es eine Untersuchung eines Linguisten dazu?

Comment: Es ist in der Tat nicht eindeutig geklärt. Der [Duden][1] tendiert zur Herleitung *rasen*. Du findest aber auch Quellen, die nur die Erklärung mit dem *Rosensonntag* zu Tage bringen.


  [1]: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rosenmontag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wie in den Kommentaren zur Frage bereits beschrieben, gibt es verschiedene mögliche Ursprünge der Bezeichnung "Rosenmontag":

1. niederrhein. rasen, köln. rose = rasen, toben, tollen, demzufolge Rosenmontag = rasender (wilder, toller) Montag (siehe Duden, Grimms Wörterbuch)
2. Aus dem Buch [Zur Etymologie lexikalisierter Farbwortverbindungen](http://books.google.de/books?id=4FtclaWzNfkC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=etymologie%20rosenmontag&source=bl&ots=QE212rDrfb&sig=_9yz40iBCF7Dh5DxkdQCzzUwPxs&hl=de&sa=X&ei=oUBCT6_YOMXltQaLz_HMBA&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) von PD Dr. habil. Christiane Wanzek, Fußnote 801:

   > Der Name Rosenmontag ist nicht von dem Verb *rasen* (toben, sich toll gebärden) abzuleiten, sondern von dem "Komitee, das seit 1824 die Umzüge des Kölner Karnevals vorbereitet" und seine Generalversammlungen am Montag nach dem Sonntag Laetare abhielt. Seit dem 11. Jahrhundert trägt der Sonntag Laetare den Namen *Rosensonntag*, weil der Papst in Rom an diesem Tag eine goldene Rose in der Hand hielt. Somit gab sich das Komitee den Namen "Rosenmontagsgesellschaft". Es war verantwortlich für die Umzüge am Fastnachtsmontag. Der Name *Rosenmontag* wurde auf den Fastnachtsmontag übertragen und tauchte seit 1830 in Köln auf (Moser 1986: 21). Anzumerken ist noch, daß es sich bei der Bezeichnung *Rosenmontag* um eine neuere Wortbildung handelt. In älteren Quellen ist der *Rosenmontag* nicht belegt.

   Dr. Wanzek bezieht sich dabei auf Dietz-Rudolf Moser: [Fastnacht-Fasching-Karneval](http://books.google.de/books/about/Fastnacht_Fasching_Karneval.html?id=4_7ZAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) (1986). Leider zeigt ausgerechnet Seite 21 bei Google Books nichts an. Für diese Erklärung gibt es bestimmt noch frühere Quellen als 1986.

   Auch Meyers Enzyklopädisches Lexikon von 1977 vertritt diese Ansicht. 
   Meyers Konversationslexikon von 1909 macht keine Angaben über die Herkunft der Bezeichnung.

Comment: Eine verlässliche Referenz wäre vielleicht ein schriftliches Beschlussprotokoll des Komitees bezüglich der eigenen Benennung, falls sowas noch oder überhaupt existiert. :(

Comment: [Kölner Karneval von Helene Klauser](http://books.google.de/books?id=FF5ssNmiTTEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Helene+Klauser%22&hl=de&sa=X&ei=mlZCT7e4Asq3-wbKuoXNAg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA) meint, dass ursprünglich 1831 der *"Rohsenmontag"* von *rohsen = rasen* herkommt, erst danach 1834 kam die Rose ins Spiel. [Heutige Kölner](http://www.koelnerkarneval.de/129.html) meinen aber, dass der Dialekt mit *"Rusemondaach"* eindeutig auf die Rose hinweise.

Comment: Das Protokoll von 1827 ist wohl im [Kölner Karnevalsmuseum](http://www.kk-museum.de/cms/front_content.php?idcat=3) zu sehen.